# Explain Four Basic Axioms of Maximising Expected Utility

Tags: expected-return, utility-theory, theory, expected

I begin learn PRM , Someone help me understand Four Basic Axioms of Maximising Expected Utility most intuitive way .Thank you very much
[image]

Comment: See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_utility_hypothesis

Answer (score 1):

Here's a try/start:

Let $A,B$, and $C$ be three possible events, and let $U(event)$ be the utility derived from each event.  For example, if event $A$ corresponds to the event of winning the lottery, then $U(A)$ will presumably be a very large value.  By contrast, if event $C$ corresponds to the event of falling off a ladder and breaking an arm, $U(C)$ will likely be a very small value.

1. Transitivity:  if $U(A)>U(B)$ and $U(B)>U(C)$, then $U(A)>U(C)$
2. Continuity: if $U(A)>U(B)>U(C)$, then $\exists p \in [0,1]$ such that 
   $$U(B) = pU(A) + (1-p)U(C)$$
   i.e. the utility function $U(event)$ is a [continuous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition)
3. Independence of Choice: (?)
4. Stochastic Dominance: if $U(A) = U(B)$, then if we *must* choose between $A$ and $B$, we ought to choose the one that is more likely to occur